# Launching new script when GPU has enough free memory

Tags: centos, nvidia

I'm working with a Centos Cluster, sharing Nvidia GPUs with other people. Each node on the cluster has 4 GPUs. I'm hoping to find a way to periodically monitor the 4 GPUs and start a (bash/python) script whenever a GPU has more free RAM than a pre-defined threshold.

I'd imagine that it should be possible to parse the output of `nvidia-smi` but this sounds rather complicated to me.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: What are you using to schedule jobs on the cluster?  Depending on the scheduler, you can just have the jobs set limits on GPU memory, and let the scheduler start jobs when other jobs complete.

Comment: I can start jobs interactively / directly from the bash terminal.

Comment: @matohak Hi, did you find a way for this ? (other than using cluster management system like slurm ?)

Comment: I've put this idea aside but I know it'd be easy to use GPUtils in python to monitor GPU memory and launch script: `import GPUtil; gpus = GPUtil.getGPUs(); if gpus[0].memoryFree > 6000: launchscript`